# how to convert pmd xml format files into junit html format files

Tags: pmd, tslint

I have Tslint to get pmd reports and I want them to convert the pmd xmls to html page to publish, how do I do that?

I also wants to invoke it in bitbucket precommit hooks, Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a saperate target for this:

```
<target name="pmd-html">
    <antcall target="pmd-internal">
      <param name="format-type" value="html"/>
    </antcall>
  </target>
```

Here you specify the formal value as html. A similar one will be there for xml. You should find it in static-analysis xml. Then in build.xml, you can create a target name `static-analysis-html`
 which depends on that `pmd-html`

```
<target name="static-analysis-html" depends="pmd-html"/>
```